# How to refer variable name in .common tag in gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab yaml file. I have variables part and .common tag part in it as below:

```
variables:
  name: app
  env: prod

.common:
  tags:
    - &env_tag prod
```

My question is can we pass the **env** variable to .common tag part. While trying to refer the variable name,  it was failing

I have tried as below:

```
.common:
  tags:
    - &env_tag $env
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible right now as gitlab does not support variable expansion in `tags`.
There are currently multiple open issues regarding this feature:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/24207